# How to get iOS 4 work with Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am not able to test my apps on my iPhone 3GS that runs iOS 4 with Xcode 3.1.4.

I can't install Xcode 3.2 because it appears it needs Mac OS X 10.6 and above.

What are my options here then, because I don't want to pay for OS X 10.6. Is it possible to just have an upgrade?

If this is totally binding, is it possible to downgrade my phone from iOS 4 to iOS 3.1?

Comment: Why don't you just pay for 10.6 since it's so inexpensive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you just lay down the money for 10.6.

Apple are moving forward and not looking back. You can't stay on 10.5 forever, especially if you're a developer. You need to be working with the latest tools and SDKs in order to benefit from bug fixes and performance improvements.

Downgrading isn't officially supported, so that's something you'll have to find out how to do yourself, and may lead to problems/difficulties and may even make your iPhone unusable. (just stating the risks).

Comment: _Apple are moving forward and not looking back._ Not looking back means, not caring about existing customers. Visual Studio 2010 can be installed on Windows XP which is released 9 years before...

Comment: I don't dispute that VS can be run on older versions of Windows. Apple aren't Microsoft though. You've seen how Apple obsolete hardware every 6 months with newer revisions. They've completely dropped support for all PPC processors, 10.5 will be deprecated as soon as 10.7 is released. Apple are fundamentally different. They may support existing consumers through the transitions, but they expect developers to be using the latest tools. The current developer toolset is 10.6 only and thats how it's going to be moving forward...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but I think this will work. You can try creating an ad-hoc distribution profile for your iPhone with the app id and install your app on the iPhone through iTunes. This way you'll be able to test your app but you can't debug it for sure.

Comment: I'll try that. So without Mac OSX 10.6 you can't debug on iOS 4? In other words, Apple is forcing me to get Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 0):

Ad-hoc distribution is the only way can get it work and I dont think that you can install iOS 3.1 in iPhone 3GS in your case.